Reorder for smallest largest prefix sum
Given a multiset of integers, order them such that the largest absolute prefix sum $$\max_i \left| \sum_{k<i} a_k \right|$$ is smallest. Output any solution if multiple exist.
You can assume input is sorted if it helps.
Test cases:
[1,2,3,4,5] => (Any order)
[-5,-4,1,2,3] => [1,2,-4,3,-5] (or other solutions with value 3)
[-8,4] => [4,-8]
[-9, 4, 9, -6] => [4, -9, 9, -6] (suggested by Jonathan Allan)

Shortest code wins.

This needs a plain English description and a worked example.

I was wondering if there might be a non-brute-force polynomial-time approach for solving this, but, alas, it's not hard to construct instances of this that embed the Subset Sum problem which is NP hard. So solutions are going to have to be exponential-time.

@xnor Subset Sum problem is NP hard only if numbers are exponentially large. Is polynomial possible if they aren't?

Suggested test case [-9, 4, 9, -6] => [4, -9, 9, -6]

I don't know what is unclear about this question. While the current description is terse there is no ambiguity.

I found it very difficult to understand before I looked at some of the answers.  I think Shaggy's request for a worked-example is reasonable.

@DominicvanEssen I'm replying to the close vote not Shaggy's comment. Challenge is clear, I don't think it's very well explained.  Although I think the nature of the challenge a worked example wouldn't be so helpful.

Should it be edited to say "assume input is sorted"? Otherwise any program that accepts any-order inputs and produces valid outputs should, by definition, also accept sorted inputs, so there is no reason to say "my submission can also take unsorted inputs"

Vyxal, 6 bytes
Ṗ≬¦ȧG∵

Try it Online!
     ∵ # Smallest
Ṗ      # Permutation
 ≬---  # By
    G  # Largest
   ȧ   # Absolute
  ¦    # Cumulative sum


Python 3, 93 bytes
lambda a:min(permutations(a),key=lambda a:max(map(abs,accumulate(a))))
from itertools import*

Try it online!
-45 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan
-3 bytes thanks to no comment

Python 3.8 (pre-release), 104 bytes
f=lambda a:a and min((f((a:=a[1:]+[x])[:-1])+[x]for x in a),key=lambda a,i=0:max(abs(i:=i+x)for x in a))

Try it online!
Solution without itertools

Save a bunch importing the permutations function - TIO

@JonathanAllan fair enough

Oh, you got close I see, impressive.

Is there a problem with accumulate? That is, key=lambda a:max(map(abs,accumulate(a)))

@nocomment thanks! itertools and all its children have very lengthy names, so I try to avoid them as much as I can :)

Pretty much the real life correct pythonic solution!

R, 124 108 104 bytes
Edit: -13 bytes thanks to Giuseppe.
Edit2: -4 bytes thanks to pajonk
\(x,n=sum(x|1),m=combn(rep(1:n,n),n))x[m[,order(apply(m,2,\(v)max(cumsum(x[v])^2)/all(table(v)<2)))[1]]]

Attempt This Online!
How?

Get all combinations v of all indices of input x (including re-use of each index, since there isn't an easy base-R command to get permutations).
Calculate max(abs(cumsum(x[v]))) for each.
Divide by all(table(v)<2))): this is zero for combinations with re-used indices, giving Inf after division.
Get the minimum, and select the elements of the input using the corresponding indices.


Would combn work here? 111 bytes -- I think it should work but it gives different answers than yours and I didn't bother verifying.

-4 bytes using table to check duplicates.

@Giuseppe, pajonk - Great improvements, thanks to both of you!

05AB1E, 8 bytes
œΣηOÄà}н

Try it online or verify all test cases
or verify all possible outputs (by using an additional group-by after the sort).
Explanation:
œ       # Get all permutations of the (implicit) input-list
 Σ      # Sort this list of permutation-lists by:
  ηO    #  Cumulative sum:
  η     #   Get the prefixes
   O    #   Sum each prefix together
    Ä   #  Take the absolute value of each sum
     à  #  Pop and leave the maximum of those
 }н     # After the sort by: take the first/smallest
        # (which is output implicitly as result)


Factor + math.combinatorics, 55 bytes
[ <permutations> [ cum-sum vabs supremum ] infimum-by ]

Try it online!

<permutations> [ ... ] infimum-by Get the smallest permutation by function [ ... ]. The angle brackets aren't special; it's just a naming convention signifying that it's a virtual sequence (similar to a lazy list).
cum-sum cumulative sum
vabs vectorized absolute value
supremum largest


Arturo, 58 bytes
$=>[minimum permutate&'p->max map size p=>[abs∑take p&]]

Try it!
Explanation
$=>[]                   ; a function where input is assigned to &
minimum permutate&'p->  ; minimum permutation of input by; current perm is p
max                     ; max value in
map size p=>[]          ; map over current perm's indices, assign to &
abs                     ; absolute value
∑                       ; sum
take p&                 ; current prefix of current permutation


R, 136 bytes
\(x)(~x)[order(apply(~x,1,\(v)max(abs(cumsum(v)))))[1],]
`~`=\(v)`if`(n<-sum(v|1),{X={};for(i in 1:n)X=rbind(X,cbind(v[i],~v[-i]));X},v)

Attempt This Online!
Permutations in base R are a pain. Code for permutations adapted from here.

Fails for [-9, 4, 9, -6] (minimal max absolute of prefix sums is 5 with [4, -9, 9, -6]).

I think this fails for input of c(1,-2,2,-1)...

Thanks for spotting that

JavaScript (ES6), 99 bytes
Naive method trying all possible permutations.
f=(a,s=M=f,m,...p)=>m>M||a.map((v,i)=>f(a.filter(_=>i--),q=~~s+v,q*q<m?m:q*q,...p,v))+a?o:(M=m,o=p)

Try it online!
Commented
f = (             // f is a recursive function taking:
  a,              //   a[] = input array
  s =             //   s = current sum (initially NaN'ish)
  M = f,          //   M = minimum of maximums (initially NaN'ish)
  m,              //   m = maximum of squared cumulative sums
                  //       (initially undefined)
  ...p            //   p[] = current permutation
) =>              //
m > M ||          // abort if m is greater than M
a.map((v, i) =>   // otherwise, for each value v at index i in a[]:
  f(              //   do a recursive call:
    a.filter(_ => //     pass a[] ...
      i--         //       ... without the i-th element
    ),            //     end of filter()
    q = ~~s + v,  //     define q as s + v
    q * q < m ?   //     if q² is less than m:
      m           //       leave m unchanged
    :             //     else:
      q * q,      //       set m to q²
    ...p,         //     append to p[] ...
    v             //     ... the new element v
  )               //   end of recursive call
) + a             // end of map()
?                 // if we had m > M or a[] is not empty:
  o               //   just return o[]
:                 // else:
  (M = m, o = p)  //   update M to m and o[] to p[]


Raku, 41 bytes
*.permutations.min:{([\+] @$_)>>.abs.max}

[\+] is the cumulative sum (+\ in APL).
>>. acts like .map{} (in theory, it might be parallelized, but its results are guaranteed to be in order).
Try it online!

Haskell + hgl, 16 bytes
mB(xM av<scp)<pm

Attempt This Online!
Explanation

pm get all permutations
mB minimum by ...
scp cumulative sums
xM av maximum absolute value

Reflection
This is a fairly straight forward solution. I don't see any potential other ways to do this. Nor do I see any ways in which two or more of the components here might be combined to make this shorter.

Haskell, 86 bytes
import Data.List
h=maximum.map abs.scanl1(+)
f=minimumBy((.h).compare.h).permutations

Try it online
Equivalent, more readable version:
import Data.List
partialSums = scanl1 (+)
helper = maximum . map abs . partialSums
answer = minimumBy (\left right -> compare (helper left) (helper right)) . permutations


Jelly, 8 bytes
Œ!ÄAṀƊÞḢ

A monadic Link that accepts a list of integers and yields one with the minimal maximum absolute prefix sum.
Try it online! Or see the test-suite.
How?
Œ!ÄAṀƊÞḢ - Link: list of integers, A
Œ!       - all permutations of A
      Þ  - sort by:
     Ɗ   -   last three links as a monad:
  Ä      -     cumulative sums
   A     -     absolute value (vectorises)
    Ṁ    -     maximum
       Ḣ - head


Charcoal, 51 bytes
⊞υ⟦⟧Ｆθ≔ΣＥυＥ⁻Ｅθνκ⁺κ⟦μ⟧υＦυＵＭι§θκ≔Ｅυ⌈↔ＥιΣ…ι⊕μη⭆¹§υ⌕η⌊η

Attempt This Online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
⊞υ⟦⟧Ｆθ≔ΣＥυＥ⁻Ｅθνκ⁺κ⟦μ⟧υ

Generate all of the permutations of the indices of the input. This is taken from my answer to Count N-Rich Permutations of an Integer Sequence. I use the indices because they're unique and it makes it easier to generate the permutations.
ＦυＵＭι§θκ

Map each index to the actual value from the input list.
≔Ｅυ⌈↔ＥιΣ…ι⊕μη

Calculate the maximum prefix sum for each permutation.
⭆¹§υ⌕η⌊η

Output the permutation with the minimum sum.

Setanta, 225 193 192 191 bytes
Another brute-force solution, but in a language without a permutation builtin.
gniomh(l){s:=eas@mata(999)p:=0gniomh f(v,w,n,m){ma fad@v<fad@l le i idir(0,fad@l){ma aimsigh@v(i)<0{N:=l[i]f(v+[i],w+[N],n+N,uas(dearbh@mata(n+N),m))}}no ma m<s{p=w s=m}}f([],[],0,0)toradh p}

Try on try-setanta.ie

Uiua + experimentals, 19 bytes
⊡⊢⍏/↥⌵\+⍉.⧅≠⊸⧻

Try it online at the Uiua pad
⊡⊢⍏/↥⌵\+⍉.⧅≠⊸⧻
⊡⊢⍏             minimum by
   /↥           maximum
     ⌵          absolute
      \+        prefix sum
        ⍉.      of each
          ⧅≠⊸⧻  permutation of the input


J, 37 31 30 bytes
0{[:{{y/:>./|+/\|:y}}i.@!@#A.]

Attempt This Online!
i.@!@#A.] NB. get the permutations:
i.        NB. the range to
  @!      NB. the factorial of
    @#    NB. the length of the argument
      A.] NB. select those permutations of the argument

0{[:{{y/:>./|+/\|:y}} NB. reorder for smallest largest prefix sum:
0{[:                  NB. first of
    {{y/:       |:y}} NB. sorting those by each's
         >./          NB. maximum
            |         NB. absolute
             +/\      NB. prefix sum


Elisp, 341 330 Bytes
Edit: learned the sort function
(defun x (bag)(if (null bag)'(())(mapcan #'(lambda (e)(mapcar #'(lambda (p) (cons e p))(x(cl-remove e bag :count 1))))bag)))(defun z (a)(car (car (sort(cl-loop for e in (x a) collect(let ((i (cons e (apply 'max(cl-loop for o = (reverse e) then (cdr o) while o collect(abs (apply '+ o)))))))i))'(lambda (j k)(< (cdr j) (cdr k))))))

Used permutation method from here https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2009-06/msg00094.html
(defun permutations (bag)
  (if (null bag)
  '(())
(mapcan #'(lambda (e)
        (mapcar #'(lambda (p) (cons e p))
            (permutations
             (cl-remove e bag :count 1))))
    bag)))
(defun smallest-largest-prefix-sum (a)
  (car (car (sort
     (cl-loop for e in (permutations a) collect
          (let ((i (cons e (apply 'max
                      (cl-loop for o = (reverse e) then (cdr o) while o collect
                           (abs (apply '+ o))
                           )
                      )
                 )))i))
     '(lambda (j k)
        (< (cdr j) (cdr k))))
    )))

